# Exact sequence of free abelian groups, $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\text{rank}(F_i)=0$.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, exact-sequence

This question is from Rotman's Introduction to the Theory of Groups:

(i) Suppose we have an exact sequence of free abelian groups $A\to B\to C\to D$ with maps $f,g,h$ in between. Show $B\cong \text{im}( f)\oplus \ker (h)$.

(ii) Given an exact sequence of free abelian groups ($n\geqslant 1$)

$$0\to F_n\to \cdots\to F_1\to F_0\to0$$

Show $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\text{rank}(F_i)=0$.

It's probably worth mentioning that on (ii), the book actually says $\sum_{i=0}^n\text{rank}(F_i)=0$, which I'm assuming is a typo because it fails for the sequence $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\to0$ with the identity in the middle. I'm just taking a guess on my correction because that's clearly true for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Anyways, (i) is simple, just note that $B/\ker (g)\cong\text{im}(g)$ which is a subgroup of a free abelian group and hence free. Therefore 
$$B\cong \ker(g)\oplus(B/\ker(g))\cong\ker(g)\oplus\text{im}(g)=\text{im(}f)\oplus\ker(h)$$

I'm struggling with (ii). I don't really know where to begin. I wanted to try an induction argument but I don't see a way I can get a shorter exact sequence of the same form from this one. I think I should probably be using (i), but I'm not sure where I can apply it. Any ideas?

Comment: i'm not sure that your argument for (i) is good enough. Why does the first isomoprhism hold? however, how about using a dimension counting argument?

Comment: You are correct about the typo.

Comment: @rhl it's a theorem we learned in the book. If a quotient $G/H$ of a free abelian group $G$ is free itself, then $G=H\oplus K$ where $K\cong G/H$. And yeah, I'll give that a try

Comment: ah yeah, thats true.

Comment: For (ii), tensor with the flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Q}$ and reduce it to a linear algebra problem.

Comment: A similar statement holds true when you have vector spaces in place of your groups. The idea behind the proof there is to use the rank-nullity theorem, so I guess you can do something similar here. Since a free abelian group is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module, if you tensor with the flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Q}$, you'll get an exact sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$ vector spaces with the dimensions equal to the number of $\mathbb{Z}$ summands (i.e. the rank).

Comment: Thanks for the idea of tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$. The way I ended up being most comfortable with was the purely group-theoretic approach given in the answer here, but that's a really nice way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (ii), try splitting your exact sequence into two exact sequences of the form $$0\to K \to F_{n-2}\to \cdots\to F_1\to F_0\to0$$ and $$0\to F_n\to F_{n-1}\to K \to 0.$$

Comment: This worked! Thanks.